# Batch or CMD to convert multi-line txt file to single line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, multiline

So I am running a batch file that does all kinds of commands and then outputs the results into output.txt

It looks like this: 
Output.txt:

AAAAA

,BBBBB

,CCCCC

,DDDDD

Is it possible to run a command within the same batch file to use my finished (output.txt) have it move all the lines to a single line so it looks like this:

AAAAA,BBBBB,CCCCCC,DDDDD

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i in ("temp2.txt") do @<nul set /p"=%%i ">>"new.txt"

which works except it adds spaces so its like this AAAAA, BBBBB, CCCCC, DDDDD

Instead of AAAAA,BBBBB,CCCCCC,DDDDD

Comment: This can be done in a single command. (If you don't know where to start, look at the output of `for /?`, specifically the `/F` flag.)

Comment: And did you try deleting the space in your code after `%%i`?

Comment: IT WORKED THANK YOU!!! I DIDNT EVEN NOTICE IT!

for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i in ("temp2.txt") do @<nul set /p"=%%i">>"new.txt"

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i in ("INPUT.txt") do @<nul set /p"=%%i">>"OUTPUT.txt"
```